# Why is the 0 needed after "(arr[i] || 0)"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For the code below I wonder why the the last "0" after "(arr[i] || 0)" is needed?

I aknowledge that without this "0" the code doesnt run as intended, but I do not actually get what that last "0" after "," makes it work.

Could someone explain it?

```js
function addTogether (...arrays) {
    let result = [];
    let arrayLength = Math.max(...arrays.map(array => array.length));
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      result.push(arrays.reduce((sum, arr) => sum + (arr[i] || 0), 0));
    }
    return result
  }
  
  test(addTogether([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]), [11, 7, 3]);
```

Comment: If `arr[i]` is `null` or `undefined`, it ensures a number is returned (`0`)....After re-reading, it looks like you are referring to the last `0` in `sum + (arr[i] || 0), 0` ??

Comment: The `0` after the comma is the initial accumulator value for `.reduce()`.

Comment: It should be noted by those who closed this question that the OP was **not** asking about the 0 in `|| 0`, but about the 0 in argument position 2 of the `.reduce()` call.

Comment: Thanks, it is very clear now!